# NaN in data frame: when first observation of time series is NaN, frontfill with first available, otherwise carry over last / previous observation

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, missing-data, statsmodels

I am performing an ADF-test from statsmodels. The value series can have missing obversations. In fact, I am dropping the analysis if the fraction of NaNs is larger than c. However, if the series makes it through the I get the problem, that the adfuller cannot deal with missing data. Since this is training data with a minimum framesize, I would like to do:

1) if x(t=0) = NaN, then find the next non-NaN value (t>0)
2) otherwise if x(t) = NaN, then x(t) = x(t-1)

So I am compromising here my first value, but making sure the input data has always the same dimension. Alternatively, I could fill if the first value is missing with 0 making use of the limit option from dropna.

From the documentation the different option are not 100% clear to me:
method : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None

> Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill /
>   bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap

pad / ffill: does that mean I carry over the previous value?
backfill / bfill: does that mean I the value is taken from a valid one in the future?

```
df.dropna(method = 'bfill', limit 1, inplace = True)
df.dropna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
```

Would that work with limit? The documentation uses 'limit = 1' but has predetermined a value to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) if x(t=0) = NaN, then find the next non-NaN value (t>0) 2) otherwise if x(t) = NaN, then x(t) = x(t-1)

To front-fill all observations except for (possibly) the first ones, which should be backfilled, you can chain two calls to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), the first with `method='ffill'` and the second with `method='fill'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, None, 1, None, 2, None]})
>>> df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
    a
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   2.0
5   2.0
```

Comment: thank you, very elegant. First front-fill all, which would lead to NaN of the first obervation if it's a NaN, and then use backfill.

Comment: Where do I have to place: inplace = true?, behind both?

Comment: If you want to do `inplace=True` then you need to do it in both, but then you can't use method chaining, and need to write `df.fillna(...)` and then again `df.fillna(...)`.

Comment: thanks Ami, in this case either twice inplace or
df = df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')