# Statsmodels: requires arrays without NaN or Infs - but test shows there are no NaNs or Infs

Tags: pandas, missing-data, statsmodels

I am trying to run an ADF-test from the statsmodels' adfuller module. It gives me an error:

```
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Via another question I could replace my NaNs ([NaN in data frame: when first observation of time series is NaN, frontfill with first available, otherwise carry over last / previous observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663350/nan-in-data-frame-when-first-observation-of-time-series-is-nan-frontfill-with/49665469?noredirect=1#comment86374410_49665469).

Although I checked for NaNs and inf:

```
df[pd.isnull(df).any(axis=1)]
np.isinf(df).any()
np.isnan(df).any()
```

which gives me "no results" for the pandas statement and both "false" for the numpy statements, my function still tells me the same error.

Is there a bug?

[ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs during Biclustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774081/valueerror-array-must-not-contain-infs-or-nans-during-biclustering)

Comment: `df.replace(np.inf,np.nan).isnull().any()`

Comment: Show the traceback or at least the end that shows where the exception is raised. There is not enough information to make even a "wild guess". A MWE would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it now via:

```
 x = pd.DataFrame(x.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan))
 x = x.fillna(method='ffill')
 x = x.fillna(method='bfill')
 x = x.iloc[:, 0]
```

which gives me a x series without any nan of inf. Problem was the switch from series to dataframe and the back to series